# ScrollView with StackView Inside Programmatically Not Scrolling

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, scrollview

I am making a `UIScrollView` with a `UIStackView` inside it programmatically.

The `UIScrollView` does not scroll even though the `UIStacVview` that is inside it has a much larger width.

**Here is my code:**

```
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.161, green: 0.165, blue: 0.188, alpha: 1.00) // 292a30

    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    view3.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    view4.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view5.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: view.frame.width - 20, height: 100)
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    stackView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    stackView.spacing = 10
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width + 200, height: 100)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(view1)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(view2)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(view3)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(view4)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(view5)

    scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

**What is working:**

1. The `UIStackView` loads and looks like this:

[image]

2. The `UIStackView` stretches out the side of the `UIScrollView`.

**What is not working:**

1. You cannot scroll with the `UIScrollView`, it is just like it isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - When you use frame-layout then don't set:

```
scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

(That is for when you set constraints programmatically.)

2 - For the scrollView either use:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 200 * 5, height: 100)
```

(Above I suppose width of each view is 200 and number of them equals 5.)

**OR**

Use Constraints.

Comment: do I remove `scrollView.frame = etc..` and replace it with `2`?

Answer (score 0):

After various attempts i am able to make it horizontally scrollable and without overlapping.

```
func createHorizontalStackViewsWithScroll() {

 self.view.addSubview(stackScrollView)
 stackScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 stackScrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 85).isActive = true
 stackScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
 stackScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
 stackScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: visualEffectViews.topAnchor).isActive = true
 stackScrollView.addSubview(stackView)

 stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackScrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
 stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackScrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
 stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackScrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
 stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackScrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
 stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackScrollView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

 stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
 stackView.spacing = 5
 stackView.axis = .horizontal
 stackView.alignment = .fill


 for i in 0 ..< images.count {
 let photoView = UIButton.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 85, height: 85))
 // set button image
 photoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 photoView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: photoView.frame.height).isActive = true
 photoView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: photoView.frame.width).isActive = true

 stackView.addArrangedSubview(photoView)
 }
 stackView.setNeedsLayout()

 }
```